# Why I have this error: ModuleNotfound error python3

Tags: python-3.x, modulenotfounderror

I have the next structure on my project:

[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAMgt.jpg)

I'm trying to run the file tests/test.py that has the next content:

```
import unittest
from machinetranslation.translator import english_to_french, french_to_english

class TestMain(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_EnglishToFrench(self):
        test_case = "Hello"
        expected = "Bonjour"        
        self.assertEqual(english_to_french(test_case), expected)

    def test_FrenchToEnglish(self):
        test_case = "Bonjour"
        expected = "Hello"        
        self.assertEqual(french_to_english(test_case), expected)

    def test_EnglishToFrench_null(self):
        test_case = None
        expected = "Type a text in English"
        self.assertEqual(english_to_french(test_case), expected)

    def test_FrenchToEnglish_null(self):
        test_case = None
        expected = "Type a text in French"
        self.assertEqual(french_to_english(test_case), expected)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

But I don't know why I'm getting the error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'machinetranslation'"
Could anyone tell me why this error please, thanks

Comment: Try "from translator import english_to_french, french_to_english"

Comment: doesn't works, I also tried: import machinetranslation.translator as tr and then tr.english_to_french(), tr.french_to_english() but not works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also encountered this issue before, this is what helped me:

```
import os, sys
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
parent_dir = os.path.dirname(current_dir)
sys.path.insert(0, parent_dir)

// Import files here
```

Comment: This solve the problem, but do you know why? or anyone

Comment: Read the "Importing your code" and "Adding Folder to the Path" section of this article: https://www.pythonforthelab.com/blog/complete-guide-to-imports-in-python-absolute-relative-and-more/